# ValueError при выдаче страницы в Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Все по туториалу, без всякой выдумки, но при переходе http://127.0.0.1:8000/about

ValueError at /about
The view main.views.about didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.

**views.py** :

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    render(request, 'main/index.html')
#    return HttpResponse("<h4>Hello, World</h4>")

def about(request):
#    return HttpResponse("<h4>OUR PAGE</h4>")
    render(request, 'main/about.html', {})
```

Хотя когда return HttpResponse проблемы нет.

Сам main\templates\main\about.html :

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>About</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>About us</h1>
<p>About us.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

```
C:\Users\user>python -V
Python 3.9.7
```

Трэйсинг :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\web1\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\web1\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 204, in _get_response
    self.check_response(response, callback)
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\web1\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 332, in check_response
    raise ValueError(
```

Comment: Вы должны возвращать ответ из своей вьюхи. На примере который вы прикрепили, return отсутствует, попробуйте его добавить. То есть, "return render...."

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так

```
 return render(request,'main/adout.html',context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: Нет параметра context_instance, есть параметр context, но такое значение он не приемлет - попробовал.   
Exception Value: 
context must be a dict rather than RequestContext.

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).